# How to create many events without creating many timer objects

Tags: c#

I am setting up a system to allow users to create custom queries that run at various intervals.  So I could have 7 that run every 4 minutes, 10 that run every 6 minutes, and 3 that run every 10 minutes. (It could be many more though).  What is the best way to set this up without just creating a bunch of timer objects?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: One timer which fires *every minute* and when when it's fired it runs required queries (if the `minute == 20` we run queries that are every 4 minutes, and every 3 minutes)

Comment: It seems like your common value is a minute. So you just need one timer that fires an event every 1 minute. When the event method is entered, just have an if statement for each interval that you have.

Comment: Please show your code :)

Comment: For each query, store a record indicating how often it should run and when it was last run. At regular intervals (like once per minute) inspect them all. If it's supposed to run every three minutes but was last run for minutes ago, run it. It's worth noting that the word "even" creates a little bit of confusion because the question is about doing things at intervals. "Event" means something specific, and the question isn't really about events.

Comment: Do you need to run more than once per query for a client? like lets say user A wants to run his query in 6 minutes, will it only return once or every 6 minutes he will be waiting for an answer?

Comment: I'd recommend using a library like Quartz or Hangfire for something like this. See https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ or https://www.hangfire.io/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to have a timer that ticks every minute and a variable that keeps track of the minutes.  Then use an `if` statement to execute the tasks when the minute is a multiple of the desired time.  This way you can have one timer serving multiple intervals.

For example:

```
private int timerCount = 0;

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Increase this counter each time the timer ticks.
    timerCount++;

    if (timerCount % 3 == 0)
    {
        //Do tasks that should execute every 3 minutes
    }

    if (timerCount % 10 == 0)
    {
        //Do tasks that should execute every 10 minutes
    }
}
```

Comment: This is simple and elegant. I'd add that you should run tasks inside the `if` blocks so the timer thread isn't blocked.

Comment: Do note that if you leave this running for over 68 years it will go out of range ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since users create these tasks, you'll have to store them somewhere, likely a database. The question doesn't specify how a user will define the task, but that's not really at the core of the question.

In your database you might have two tables. One is a definition of the task which includes the interval after which it should run. This could be stored in minutes or seconds depending on the expected use.

Another table would contain the history of executing those tasks. Each time a task is executed, store a new record. It might include the outcome as well.

Then, once per minute (or so) retrieve a list of tasks joined to the history to show the most recent execution for each task. One at a time, compare the last execution time to the interval. That's subtracting two date/times.

```
var minutesSinceLastExecution = (lastExecutionDateTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes;
if (minutesSinceLastExecution >= minutesInterval)
    // execute the query
```

Then, after executing the query, insert a new history record.

That's a basic outline which still leaves a few questions unanswered. For example, could the time it takes a query to run be longer than the interval? Will you need to run unrelated queries simultaneously? You still have to figure out some details, and that could involve storing even more data. For example, you might want to indicate that a query is executing so that a subsequent interval doesn't start executing the same query. If you store that detail in your database as well then your process can scale across multiple servers if needed.